# Multiline subfigure caption cannot be shown fully

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

It's covered by the picture form the next line as shown below:

[image]

I've tried to set subfigure with new width or new height, but the problem is still there.

The environment of my latex is a template on overleaf, I made a simple version and uploaded in Github [here](https://github.com/dutry/temp_problem_of_my_latex/tree/master).

A simple version of the source code is as below:

```
\documentclass[type=master,fontset=fandol]{thuthesis}

\usepackage{thuthesis}

\graphicspath{{figures/}}


\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\chapter{test}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{1.eps}
    \caption{$v_l^* - l$}
  \end{subfigure}%
%  \hspace{4em}%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{2.eps}
    \caption{$\sigma_l^* - l$}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{3.eps}
    \caption{$v_b - l$}
  \end{subfigure}%
%  \hspace{4em}%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.eps}
    \caption{$\sigma_b - l$}
  \end{subfigure}

  \caption{}
  \label{fig:ov}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code snippet to complete but small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` with your code fragment is not possible to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Zarko It's from a template on overleaf( https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/tsinghua-university-thesis-template/wrjmnybpzbhw ),  you may put my code in it and reproduce the problem

Comment: Please again, make your code compilable. Your link will be soon or later dead and people will not be able to reproduce your problem. From your code fragment we can only conclude, that it is not source of your problem.

Comment: @Zarko Sorry for may fresh mind. I have uploaded the source code in GitHub [here](https://github.com/dutry/temp_problem_of_my_latex/tree/master), please feel free to check it. Best wishes!

Comment: Please, please consider my previous comments. Links to your code is not what i ask you. Just open your file in your editor, copy its content, and past it your question.  Simply like this.

Comment: @Zarko Actually the environment is a package provided by some other person, so the environment is not just simply set in a single file. You may try the source code I uploaded in Github to Overleaf, it's very easy to reproduce my problem. I think it might be caused by the [package](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/tsinghua-university-thesis-template/wrjmnybpzbhw) on the official site of overleaf.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is not willing  (after asking her/him three times) to provide MWE, which demonstrate her/his problem. Without it it is not possible to indicate problem nor help with suggestion and solutions.

Comment: @Zarko I think maybe I've just caught what you said? Could please check my question again? Is it what you asked for? Please forgive me for my rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with your MWE, after small tweak of images width (from `width=0.5\textwidth` to 0.48\textwidth`) and fixing error in document class (undefined`\bibfont`), i obtain the following result:

[image]

Corrected MWE is:

```
\documentclass[type=master,fontset=fandol, demo]{thuthesis}
\usepackage{thuthesis}
%\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\chapter{test}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{1}
    \caption{$v_l^* - l$}
  \end{subfigure}%
\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{2}
    \caption{$\sigma_l^* - l$}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{3}
    \caption{$v_b - l$}
  \end{subfigure}%
\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4}
    \caption{$\sigma_b - l$}
  \end{subfigure}

  \caption{}
  \label{fig:ov}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

- you not need to write image file tip (as you can see in MWE above)
- you should write to document class author and ask him to fix error: `\bibfont` undefined (temporally i change line 1149 from `\renewcommand\bibfont{\ifthu@bachelor\wuhao[1.619]\else\wuhao[1.5]\fi}` to `\newcommand\bibfont{\ifthu@bachelor\wuhao[1.619]\else\wuhao[1.5]\fi}`
- as you can see, images appear as expected, without any overlapping of sub-captions. if you like to have more space between sub-captions and images in the next row, insert `\medskip` or `\bigskip` before second rows of images:

```
... (images in the first row)
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
... (images in the second row)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your great patience and perfectly solved my question! I have asked the template provider to solve this issue in their source code.